# How do I make an applescript launch as soon as it exits screen saver

Tags: applescript, screensaver

I would like my mac to to say 'Login Authorized' as soon as I exit screen saver mode. Where should I place the script?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Have you tried "ScriptSaver"? http://swannman.github.io/scriptsaver/ Not used it myself, but it sounds like it does what you want?

Comment: it would be called something like "on wake up do..."

Comment: If you don't like scriptsaver, write a short script that runs continuously and [looks for the screensaver process](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1841417/check-if-screensaver-is-active-using-mac-bash-script-command). If it ends, show your message.